# WPF TreeView bound to ObservableCollection won't update when adding

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, mvvm-light, observablecollection

Have browsed similar answers, but I just can't find the problem.

I'm using MvvmLight, and have bound a WPF TreeView to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel. 
The tree shows fine, but if I add members to the ObservableCollection later on, the tree doesn't refresh.

Here's the code:

```
// the data type that represents a tree node
public class FurnitureTreeNode : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public object Data { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FurnitureTreeNode> ChildNodes { get; set;}
    public Furniture(string Name, ObservableCollection<FurnitureTreeNode> ChildNodes, object Data)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.ChildNodes = ChildNodes;
        this.Data = Data;
    }
}

public class FurnituresViewModel : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<FurnitureTreeNode> TopFurnitureNodes { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FurnitureTreeNode> ChairNodes { get; set; }

    public FurnituresViewModel()
    {
        // initialize the top level furnitures collection
        TopFurnitureNodes = new ObservableCollection<FurnitureTreeNode>();

        // add two children
        TopFurnitureNodes.Add(new FurnitureTreeNode("Tables", null, null);
        TopFurnitureNodes.Add(new FurnitureTreeNode("Chairs", null, null);

        // add Beds only when they're ready
        BedsManager.ImportsSatisfied += AddBedsNode;
    }
```

The following runs fine, the collection is updated with the Beds node, but it isn't reflected in the TreeView:

```
    void AddBedsNode( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            TopFurnitureNodes.Add(new FurnitureTreeNode("Beds", null, null);
        }
        );
    }
}
```

Here's the XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="FurnituresTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding TopFurnitureNodes}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildNodes}" DataType="x:Type FurnitureTreeNode">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does your output say?

Comment: There are no errors or anything unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew,

Please try to replace

```
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        TopFurnitureNodes.Add(new FurnitureTreeNode("Beds", null, null);
    }
    );
```

with:

```
TopFurnitureNodes.Add(new FurnitureTreeNode("Beds", null, null);
```

And let us know it this helps.

Please also make sure that you bind ViewModel to View correctly.

Comment: How do you bind your view model with your view? Does the output show any errors?

Comment: Thank you Piotr, problem solved. Indeed, the View wasn't bound correctly to the ViewModel object.

Comment: I'll update my answer then so it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your view model and raising the `PropertyChanged` event with the `PropertyName` parameter value of `TopFurnitureNodes` when you update it:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    TopFurnitureNodes.Add(new FurnitureTreeNode("Beds", null, null);
    RaisePropertyChanged("TopFurnitureNodes");
});
```

You shouldn't really need to do this, but it should work.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is already implemented through the base class GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase.

Isn't it RaisePropertyChanged("TopFurnitureNodes") ? Tried that, doesn't help.

Comment: It might be... I don't use MvvmLight, so I don't know, but I think you understood what I meant. I'll update it in my answer all the same.